# Laravel redirection to https

Tags: laravel, redirect, https

Hi i ve an app made with laravel and this address http://example.com/check/.
I wanted to redirect to https so i created this middleware

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;

    class HttpsProtocol
    {
        /**
         * Handle an incoming request.
         *
         * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
         * @param  \Closure  $next
         * @return mixed
         */
        public function handle($request, Closure $next)
        {
            if (!$request->secure()) {
                return redirect()->secure($request->getRequestUri());
            }
    
            return $next($request);
        }
    }
```

Then i added

```
    \App\Http\Middleware\HttpsProtocol::class
```

to Kernel in App/Http in protected $middlewareGroups

Redirection seems to work but redirect to this address https://example.com/check/check
with repeated URI (check)
Why
Thx a lot

Comment: Why don't you use .htaccess file to redirect?

Comment: i tried also but others www.example.com/uri.... dont work....not found page

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't need to append the request URI, that is happening already so try:

```
if (!$request->secure()) {
   return redirect()->secure();
}
```

Comment: it gives me this error Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Routing\Redirector::secure(),

Comment: if i write this it works!!   return redirect()->secure($request->getPathInfo());   Mmm why getpathinfo doesn't return just /check ?